# Upgrade SilkTest automation scripts to work with IE9

Tags: automated-testing, browsers, web, ie9

We use SilkTest 2010 Open Agent to perform Automated Web Testing.  Our scripts currently work on IE6 - IE8 and on Firefox 3.X.

IE9 has changed modal boxes to unintrusive pop-ups at the bottom of the screen which breaks our scripts.  Also, SilkTest does not recognize these pop-ups.

Recording a script without the modal boxes work fine, but when we record something that involves modal boxes, the SilkTest recorder does not retain any recorded steps (including the ones recorded before the modal box was encountered).

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: You could use this opportunity to switch to Selenium. It's a more robust framework and can run against most versions of most browsers. I realize that switching your automation tool is a big deal. But it's worth it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SilkTest 2011 as it has support for the IE 9 & FF6.
Your silk test 2010 script will run on Silk test 2011.

Answer (score 3):

If IE 9 is breaking your SilkTests you may need to check with the vendor to see what support they have.  It may or may not be supported yet.

Comment: @dan-snell SilkTest does not support IE9 yet, however, we can't wait until they upgrade their product, hence have asked this question, if someone has found a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You could try configuring IE so it does not display those troublesome modal boxes.

Otherwise, you might try scripting the relevant parts with the modal dialog manually with the help of the locator spy.

**Edit:** With newer versions of Silk Test you can enable Accessibility support for IE, which will  enable Silk Test to recognize those little overlays at the bottom in IE. You might want to enable it only for certain steps (e.g. confirming a download) as Accessibility has quite an impact on performance.

To enable/disable Accessibility in your scripts set the option `OPT_ENABLE_ACCESSIBILITY`.